# Can I invent html tag names to create multiple areas using grid layout?

Tags: html, css, tags, css-grid

I am hoping to get the benefit of expertise beyond my own, limited, skills and knowledge!

I realise that using ids (or classes) would be better for what I want to achieve here; or I could use multiple divs and manipulate them...

However I would like to reduce the amount of overhead code as much as possible and although this works, what are the downsides or the inherent problems that might arise?

I repeat: I know the amount of overhead code is negligible and that people should be learning to do this the 'proper' way; however my question still stands!...

Here is an abbreviated version to illustrate what I would like to do...

Can I MAKE UP tag names for the html, in order to refer to then label them in CSS as follows?...

Here I have made up the names <'section1'>...<'section5'> - could that cause issues? Does it break any rules?

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  padding: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "s1 s1 s1"
    "s2 s3 s3"
    "s2 s4 s4"
    "s5 s5 s5"
}
section-1{
  grid-area:s1;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
}
section-2{
  grid-area:s2;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
section-3{
  grid-area:s3;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
section-4{
  grid-area:s4;
  background-color: tan;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
section-5{
  grid-area:s5;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
    </head>
    <body class='grid'>
            <section-1> area 1
                </section-1>
            <section-2> area 2
                </section-2>
            <section-3> area 3
                </section-3>
            <section-4> area 4
                </section-4>
            <section-5> area 5
                </section-5>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note, this is a simplified version of what I want to do, purely to illustrate my invention of tags in the html and how that relates to the grid.

PS I know I could use  or parse the divs by element number in the stylesheet - but I want to know what, if anything, is wrong with my proposed method?

NB: edited to change <'section1'> to <'section-1'> etc

I hope this makes sense! TIA

Comment: No, you cannot and should not. It is an invalid markup and only works with the auto-correction of a browser. It cost poo accessibility and de-rating your SEO rating. What is wrong with giving the sections an ID or simply using `nth-child`?

Comment: Thank you, I know I could (should) use either of those methods.
What does 'cost poo accessibility' mean? Poor SEO rating is a good and valid reason for not doing it this way, is there anything else? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: read above. You "create" tags that do not exist and will give you an invalid markup error with any [markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/). This means it only works as long as a browser is able to correct your mistakes (quirks mode). If a browser does not support this auto-correction or removes that support your website will not be rendered correctly at all. Despite that, it lowers your SEO rating drastically. Makes it harder to get listed high in search engines. You make your website inaccessible to screen readers. Frankly, you should not start doing invalid stuff just because you can.

Comment: **Yes You can, but** like attributes, there is a rule to follow. You can read this https://matthewjamestaylor.com/custom-tags and it also comes with much more features than just a custom-tag  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements **So the use you want to make of it, is probably not what  it is designed for** :)

Comment: @tacoshy I know your advice is correct; however my invention of the tags does streamline the code somewhat.
<section1> becomes <div id='section1'>
and in the CSS:
section1{ becomes #section1{

...as I said in my question, this is only a small overhead!

If I want to layout a page should I mix layout tags, such as <header> and <footer>
With divs like <div id='section1'> rather than <div id='header'> - I like the consistency of the latter.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That is just the article I need to read - in it MJT states that custom tags are valid and can be used for layout elements (as I would like) - the only thing I am missing is to include a hyphen in their name. So renaming <section1> to <section-1> and so on would validate all I want to achieve.

I realise there is a danger of seeking validation and searching for the answer that suits me, so I would be interested in verifying MJT's view with tacoshy above, as they clearly clash,